# Time passed until WaitForSingleObject returned

Tags: windows, windbg

Is there a way to know how much time passed from when my call is blocked  at WaitForSingleObject function using Windbg.

Comment: the duplicate has no answers pertaining to finding the wait times using windbg it is not always possible to add gettickcount in a compiled binary  or  recompile with timer functions   the duplicate is all source level solutions not binary level solutions and one can ask windbg to print out the wait times

Comment: I do agree with @blabb. The proposed answer requires recompilation / code injection; while I think it can't be done in user-land it certainly is possible using windbg attached as a kernel debugger.

Comment: if not accurate it can be done in user mode in fact I wrote an answer explaining offline and I see this closed as dup in the meanwhile in kernelmode there is a dedicated .echotimestamps for each event

Comment: Avoid using a debugger when you meant to use a profiler.  VS has a very slick [concurrency profiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Diagnostics.ConcurrencyVisualizerforVisualStudio2015), surely what you really want if you're focusing on WFSO.

Comment: In which situation do you want to use this? Is it kind of a deadlock situation? Is it a crash dump? Is it live debugging? Are you ok with a kernel debugging solution?

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I got full memory kernel dump, from which I have too analyze my user mode process. My service is consuming too much memory. So wanted to check each thread how much time spent in WiatForSingleObject.

Answer (score 0):

source for demo compiled

```
f:\src\wait>dir /b
wait.cpp

f:\src\wait>type wait.cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        HANDLE handl = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
        DWORD res = 0;
        INPUT_RECORD record;
        DWORD numRead;
        while (res != WAIT_FAILED)
        {
                res = WaitForSingleObject(handl, 0x3000);
                printf("%x\n", res);
                if (res == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                {
                        ReadConsoleInput(handl, &record, 1, &numRead);
                        if (record.EventType == KEY_EVENT)
                        {
                                if (record.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
                                        printf("key pressed\n");
                        }
                }
        }
}
f:\src\wait>cl /nologo wait.cpp
wait.cpp

f:\src\wait>dir /b
wait.cpp
wait.exe
wait.obj
```

loading the exe in windbg and getting time on Waits

```
f:\src\wait>cdb wait.exe

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17763.132 AMD64

0:000> bp KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx ".echotime ; gc"

0:000> $$ lets find the first ret instruction and set a bp there

0:000> # ret KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx
KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x12f:
00007ffa`839f846f c3              ret
0:000> bp 00007ffa`839f846f ".echo on ret;.echotime;gc"

0:000> $$ listing the bps
0:000> bl
 0 e 00007ffa`839f8340     0001 (0001)  0:**** KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx ".echotime ; gc"
 1 e 00007ffa`839f846f     0001 (0001)  0:**** KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x12f ".echo on ret;.echotime;gc"

 0:000> executing the exe take note of interval between WAIT_TIMEOUT and WAIT_OBJECT_0 and the
 processing time of 4 ~millseconds 
0:000> g

Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:04:54.261 2019  < first hit 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:06.551 2019  <first wait_timeout
102  <--- console output of res  WAIT_TIMEOUT
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:06.555 2019  <loop and hit wait 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:18.844 2019  <second timeout 
102
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:18.848 2019 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:25.205 2019 
0
key pressed
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:25.209 2019  << 4 milliseconds 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:25.333 2019  << 113 milliseconds
0
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:25.337 2019  <hits wait again
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:25.668 2019  < timeout
0
key pressed
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:25.673 2019  < 5 milliseconds
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:25.797 2019 
0
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:25.802 2019



on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:26.196 2019 
0
key pressed
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:26.200 2019 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:26.324 2019 
0
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:26.329 2019 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:26.716 2019 
0
key pressed
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:26.721 2019 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:26.741 2019 
0
key pressed
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:26.745 2019 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:26.804 2019 
0
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:26.807 2019 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:26.845 2019 
0
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:26.849 2019 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:27.300 2019 
0
key pressed
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:27.306 2019 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:27.445 2019 
0
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:27.449 2019 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:27.797 2019 
0
key pressed
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:27.801 2019 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:27.956 2019 
0
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:27.961 2019 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:28.364 2019 
0
key pressed
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:28.370 2019 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:28.484 2019 
0
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:28.489 2019 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:40.778 2019 
102
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:40.780 2019 
on ret
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:42.292 2019 
0
key pressed
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Thu Aug 29 12:05:42.298 2019 
(1044.2984): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
00007ffa`86ad3150 cc              int     3
0:002>
```

Comment: Thanks blabb, I wanted from .dmp file. I dont have option to recompile binary